# Slow rolling power windows

Tags: honda, power-windows

I have a 2000 Honda CRV where the power windows are slow to roll up, and usually need manual assistance to fully close.  When rolling up the windows (front DS, front PS), they start up slow and usually quit about halfway up.  Pulling them or pushing them up while holding the button, gets them over the hump and they then roll up the rest of the way.

What are the possible causes of this?  What is required to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the power window motors are dying.  It's actually a fairly rare situation though, usually switches fail first.  Might be worth pulling the switches and checking/cleaning them just to make sure you're not actually having some sort of weird intermittent switch connection that's making the motor appear to be weak.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the both front window run channels are dirty and dry may want to try cleaning  and run some silicone spray down rubber run channels

Comment: +1 My windows were getting stuck halfway up and it turned out the rubber window edges just needed some cleaning and lubrication.

Comment: Sounds like the window run channels took care of it

Answer (score 1):

When the window regulators begin to fail, a window will also do this. I doubt a motor failure will do this, as the motor will be very unlikely to be moved by hand.

Added this: [Honda CRV 1997 - 2001 Replacement Window Regulator](http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/featured/wipers_-and-_windows/1461458509.html)

Comment: How would I fix that? what do the regulators do?

Comment: @Test101 The regulator is like the frame mechanism the window motor drives, and sometimes one of the gears fails and slips. Replacing this, or opening your door panel and finding the fault and repairing it are the only way to fix it. A great example is the BMW E46 window regulator, it has plastic clips that hold the window. These clips wear out all the time, so the wire can't move the window and has the effect you describe here. Look at my edit for the part I speak of.

Comment: If this was the problem, wouldn't you hear the motor trying to spin (or spinning freely)?  In my case when the window is going up, you can hear the motor lag.

Comment: @Tester101 I have seen where the wires shred, and wrap around gears seizing the motor. The motor is not actually bad, but it cannot adequately move the glass. Your best bet is to pull your door panel, and examine your regulator. It might be very obvious, and might also be easy to fix (in some cases) with a zip tie (in some cases).